# Testing discrete data for periodicity

Tags: data-visualization, data-transformation, fourier-transform

I have some data which looks roughly periodic - is there a nice way to measure this?

[image]

This is an example I'm working on and I'd like a metric that I will be able to just threshold to give a decision of yes or no. I was thinking maybe looking into the Fourier domain or looking at correlation. Many thanks.